# jQuery multiple loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to loop through the list items of several ULs of a SHOWN div.

For example in the snippet below, I want to write a generic jQuery function that will detect the shown div and iterate through list items g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n and o

What is the most efficient way to go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Example:

```
<style>
#zlt-1 {display:none;}
</style>

    <div id="zlt-1" >
    <ul class="jgrid12 first layoutFrame">
        <li>example a</li>
        <li>example b</li>
        <li>example c</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="jgrid12 first layoutFrame">
        <li>example d</li>
        <li>example e</li>
        <li>example f</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="zlt-2" >
    <ul class="jgrid12 first layoutFrame">
        <li>example g</li>
        <li>example h</li>
        <li>example i</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="jgrid4 first layoutFrame">
        <li>example j</li>
        <li>example k</li>
        <li>example l</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="jgrid8 layoutFrame">
        <li>example m</li>
        <li>example n</li>
        <li>example o</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What is it that you are asking exactly? We can do programming here, not telepathy.

Comment: geez guys, he's asking how to select VISIBLE divs.  It's not that hard to get that from his question considering he typed it in UPPERCASE.  It may not be worded perfectly, but why all the criticism?

Comment: @cwolves: He can select _visible_ divs like this `$('div:visible');`. Is that all he is asking, for us to do his two secs research?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the `:visible` selector

```
$('div:visible li').each(function(){
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a jQuery function. So, here is how you can do it:

```js
(function($){
    // define your function here
    $.fn.listIterator = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this)
                .find('ul li')
                .each(function(){
                    // do whatever you like here with list items
                });
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // use the function like this
        $('div:visible').listIterator();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[Here is a demo for you to see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/Mrwn7/)